# What is the most efficient way to select three lists with maximum number of different elements?

Tags: python, list, selection

Given a list of lists, e.g. `[[0,1], [1,3], [2,4,5], [3,7,9]]`, is there an efficient (better than brute forcing all possibilities) way to select three lists such that the number of unique elements in all three lists combined is maximized? I can only find heuristic ways, that ultimately result in the same worst-case as brute force.
This is my brute force code:

```
def maximum_number_of_elements_brute(list):
    maximum = 0
    maximum_combination = []
    for a in range(len(list)):
        for b in range(a,len(list)):
            for c in range(b,len(list)):
                number_of_elements = len(set(list[a] + list[b] + list[c]))
                if number_of_elements > maximum:
                    maximum = number_of_elements
                    maximum_combination = [a,b,c]
    return (maximum, maximum_combination)
```

The result of the function applied to the example list returns:
`([0,2,3], 8)`

Comment: What exactly do you need to maximize? The number of elements across the three selected lists, the number of *unique* elements, or their sum?

Comment: @jfaccioni The question title says *maximum number of different elements*.

Comment: @wim and the body reads *select three lists such that the number of elements in all three lists combined is maximum*, hence my confusion.

Comment: If it was maximum sum, or maximum number not considering uniqueness, then the problem would be trivial. So the maximized number unique elements is the only interpretation that makes sense IMO.

Comment: Agreed, although it wouldn't be the first time that a trivial question is asked in this site...

Comment: Sort by the length of the set of each then slice the *top* three?

Comment: @wwii What if all the three _longest_ sets have the same elements

Comment: what's the expected result in the example provided?

Comment: @DeepakGouda - Then my *read* of the spec is flawed.

Comment: Suggestions to improve your question:  1. show your brute-force and/or heuristic code, both as an example of what an efficient approach needs to beat, and what the correct result is.  2. modify the example so that it is a non-trivial case (in this example the first list is already a subset of the second list, so there's not much to do here).  3. clarify what you want to do in case the solution is non-unique - all possible solutions returned, or just pick any one?

Comment: @wim Thanks for the suggestions, I'm sorry for the imprecise question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [maximum coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem).  The fact that it is NP-hard suggests that you can’t do much better than brute force (although with a fixed *k* of 3 the asymptotic result doesn’t hold).  Certainly you can do some branch-and-bound that is *likely* to be faster: consider the largest sets first, and stop part if the search if you have a union at least as large as any that remaining sets could form.